# how to extend keycloak to support fingerprint authentication

Tags: keycloak

We have a legacy fingerprint authentication service, some other systems use it to identify users. This system uses a ActiveX with a fingerprint scan device, it can be used in desktop applications or web application, not mobile built-in fingerprint support.

How can I integrate this service with keycloak ? what are the basic steps ?

Comment: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi

Comment: @rckrd thanks, do you know what are the maven dependencies I need to build a custom authenticator?

Comment: Have a look at other extensions: https://www.keycloak.org/extensions.html